# openGL keep object size regardless of the window size

Tags: c++, opengl, size, constants

I want to create balls but when I reshape the window, the balls turn into elipses.
How can I keep the balls' size regardless of the window size?

Comment: when you adjust the view port also adjust the projection matrix to account for the new aspect ratio

Comment: Use the correct aspect ration in your projection. For more details you will have to show us how your current projection setup looks like. (and again 17 seconds too slow :( )